# Use custom javascript files functions in my JMeter test

Tags: javascript, jmeter

We have a JavaScript script that creates few Requests based on some logic when it is downloaded into client browser and I want to import the same JavaScript into JMeter to use some functions of that JavaScript in my test (Pre-Processer).

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please provide some code examples, the structure of your application, etc. with more specific details

Comment: We have a javascript that creates few Requests based on some logic when it is downloaded into client browser and I want to import the same javascript into JMeter to use some functions of that javascript in my JMeter test (Pre-processer). Please see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can load javascript function in script file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) . Choose javascript as language and write or enter your script file.

Notice that Jmeter executed in server side so it does impact client side as browser functions